# Logcat Warning Message W/PopupManager(16372)

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-logcat

> W/PopupManager(16372): You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups. Falling back to the Activity content view which may not work properly in future versions of the API. Use setViewForPopups() to set your content view.

Well After Adding Google Play Service, LogCat Giving this warning message.

Comment: Also getting the same error. and crashing the app